# Ist it possible recreate this Jquery effect using MooTools?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, mootools

I wanted to create this page expand effect with mootools. http://www.curtziegler.com/sitedemo/portfolio/education.html I've searched online and I can't seem to find anything on it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yes. just use morph?

`document.id("someid").set("morph", {
    duration: 1000
}).morph({
    height: [0, someheight]
});` etc. where someheight is pre-determined or read beforehand.

Comment: @Dimitar umm okay, how would I implement that into the document?

Comment: have a look at Fx.Slide in MooTools-More, that might be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fx.Slide class of the MooTools More package:
http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Slide